# ComboBox not binding on WCF callback

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, wsdualhttpbinding

I'm creating a sample chat application.

On Form load, WCF service is called.
-- here user's callback is registered at wcf service, added to a UserList

Other users are notified about the current users by sending the UserList to them using their callback. Callback cals `UpdateClientList` method at client side.

WCF service is able to call the Client's method "`UpdateClientList(List<PropUser> listuser)`".

But, inside the method even following hard-coded lines are not able to bind them:

```
List<PropUser> listuser = new List<PropUser>();
            listuser.Add(new PropUser { Id = "1", Name = "Ram" });
            listuser.Add(new PropUser { Id = "2", Name = "Shyam" });
            listuser.Add(new PropUser { Id = "3", Name = "Ramam" });

            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
            comboBox1.DataSource = listuser;
```

even `comboBox1.Enabled= false;` is not working

`MessageBox.Show("Hi");` is working.

Note: it is windows application not web
Please suggest:

Answer (score 0):

When you added reset the datasource do you call the update method on the Combobox ?

If you used a binding source as the intermediary - you could call ResetBindings(false); That would do the trick for you.

However in your scenario - you need to refresh your combobox by calling the Update() method on the box, combobox1.Update();